# Is there a way to call specific code right before the app is killed or moves to the background?

Tags: flutter

I want to write the user's preferences to a file before they leave the app, so I'm looking for something in Flutter like Android's onPause() or onStop() methods.  Is this something so platform-specific that I'd need to write services for it and actually use Android/iOS's specific methods for these situations or is there a way to do it only using Flutter/Dart?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184497/how-to-execute-code-before-app-exit-flutter/65101428#65101428

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understaning is that this is possible with the didChangeAppLifecycleState callback on the WidgetsBindingObserver:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

Examples:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=didChangeAppLifecycleState

We definitely need some better docs and examples here.  I've filed:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7394

If these are not sufficient for your needs, it is also possible to listen for any events in your Objective-C or Java code and forward those along to Dart via HostMessages (documented at https://flutter.io/platform-services).

Comment: The problem is that currently there is no event sent when the Activity on Android is stopped (which means the Dart VM isolate is destroyed). The [AppLifecycleState](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) has only a _paused_ event, no _destroyed_. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924890/how-do-i-run-code-in-the-background-even-with-the-screen-off/42041981

Comment: On app kill i have to call api.
Tried calling apis in dispose() method and also tried to call apis on AppLifecycleState.detached.  
both doesn't work.

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: @mayur.p did you find any solution?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is example code how you do it]

first you need to add `with WidgetsBindingObserver`
then dont forget to init & dispose the WidgetsBindng
then you can call it from  `didChangeAppLifecycleState`