# Flutter Focus App That Is Not In Foreground

Tags: flutter

I'm using the [URL Launcher](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url-launcher) flutter plugin to launch a browser with a url. How do I bring the Flutter app back to focus after viewing the URL?

Comment: It would be ideal if I can close the browser too.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41924890/7929790

Answer (score -1):

When you use URL Launcher, you invoke and give control to the operating system. Only the user of the mobile device can navigate back to the Flutter app.

If you want more control, you should navigate to a custom native UI that you control, and which is part of the Flutter app itself. For an example of such interaction between Flutter UI and native UI see this:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_view