# equivalent for "moveTaskToBack(true)" in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to keep the application running in background when pressing the back button, exactly like we press the home button. Im using flutter so i need an equivalent to "moveTaskToBack(true)" in android.

Comment: This does not solve your question but here some more background information
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924890/how-do-i-run-code-in-the-background-even-with-the-screen-off

Answer (score 3):

**03.2020 SOLUTION**

You should wrap your Scaffold with WillPopScope, so the final code should look like as below:

```
var _androidAppRetain = MethodChannel("android_app_retain");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
        return Future.value(true);
      } else {
        _androidAppRetain.invokeMethod("sendToBackground");
        return Future.value(false);
      }
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    ...
  ),
);
}
```

The code in the MainActivity() (android/app/src/main/kotlin/{yourProjectId}) should look like this:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "android_app_retain").apply {
        setMethodCallHandler { method, result ->
            if (method.method == "sendToBackground") {
                moveTaskToBack(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```