# Flutter: cross-platform way to keep application running in the background

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep a Flutter application running even if it's not in focus. For instance have a countdown running and play an alarm sound/show notification on completion, no matter what's running in foreground.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Ideally something that works cross-platform.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924890/how-do-i-run-code-in-the-background-even-with-the-screen-off/42101998#42101998) but it's almost 2 years old, so I'm thinking maybe there has been some development since then.

Comment: This looks like what you might want: https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

Answer (score 3):

This looks like what you might want: https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124. It's a nice article on Medium describing how to run things in the background on both iOS and Android, especially using the most recent releases of Flutter.

The official documentation for Flutter in the background is at https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes.  The key is to run your code in an Isolate, because you won't have access to the GUI Isolate when you are in the background.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that article.
My problem was actually much more trivial. In my timer app I used the AnimationStatus of Animation to trigger something at the end. This didn't trigger in the background (probably because there's no animation happening when the app is in the background?). If I use a Timer instead to trigger something it works just fine, even if the app is in the background.

Comment: its not a nice article really... wayyy to complex

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get my app to run in the background for quite a while now and i have finally found something that I thought might benefit others looking for a solution. The workmanager package has an unpublished branch that provides the ability to run for background code on ios upon closing the app. There seem to be little limitations except a time limit. find the pull request here:

- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/pull/511
  (This contains important information on breaking changes that are on this branch)

and the branch here:

- https://github.com/absar/flutter_workmanager/tree/ios-bg-tasks-enh-final