# Is it possible to build a 24/7 running on background APP?

Tags: react-native, flutter, background-process

I want to build a mobile app that runs 24/7 on the background, despite the app being closed or not.
This would all be with the user consent.

The app would work as follows:

- Once installed the user would open the app and login
- After that, the app would open a websocket connection with my server and handle messages and reply. I would need this to be running 24/7 after user has logged while Internet Connection exists, even if the app is closed

My question is if this is possible in any way?
And if it is, is it possible to build in a native language to avoid coding both iOS and Android? I was looking into React Native and Flutter but didn't find any specific information.

If it's not possible to maintain the app running on the background 24/7 could it be possible to do with notifications?
In this case it would work as follow:

- After receiving notification, app would handle the notification and respond back to the server (without actually showing a notification to the user to avoid spam).

If none of the approaches are possible, does anyone has a suggestion/solution?

Comment: same request, I am using socket.io instead.  I tried almost everything, even with timer in another thread, and even this timer can run 24/7, the socket is 'paused' by the system.  using background_fetch plugin can only 'wakeup' every 15 mins but socket down within 10 mins from screen off.  using push notification, cannot wakeup app without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24386

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24278

https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/1986

[How do I run code in the background, even with the screen off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924890/how-do-i-run-code-in-the-background-even-with-the-screen-off/42101998#42101998)

https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

It seems like an ongoing issue.
Your best hope is the background_fetch plugin at the moment

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/background_fetch