# run code in background(when I lock the mobile screen)

Tags: flutter, dart

When I lock the mobile screen, I want to create a timer and when Timer is ended,  UI update or send a local notification

Does anyone have best solution or code for a run in the background?

Comment: I think this can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42101998/8358956