# Flutter with Agora SDK: Can't listen audio after 1 min of locking the screen

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I have implemented the Agora SDK with my Flutter app. Now everything works fine with audio and video call. But during the audio call when I press power (lock screen) button, then after 1 min I can't listen audio of that call. Also then I pressed that lock screen button again and unlock my screen and I can listen that audio again.

This issue comes in my android app generated by flutter.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: You'll need to add some code mate

Comment: Can you please tell me what code I have to add mate? Any sample code you can give me that can help me more.

Comment: Can I see the class that handles your agora engine? That could help

Comment: I have the same issue. https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch this Fixed it for me.

Comment: @kunalmanochamay you please show some code how to use/implement with background_fetch to make this work. Am  kinda new in flutter. Some show me how to use firegroundservices although dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Executing an app in the background (when the phone is locked) is something which OS providers don't appreciate. Hence there aren't any method to run your app in the background. This is one of the ongoing issues in the flutter SDK https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671

That being said you can still add a logic to your code or probably a timer that can help you with this. You can refer this solution over here : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58065869/13055253)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use foreground service. I have same issue, solved it out by use of foreground service. When you start voice call, start the foreground service. When you end the voice call, destroy the foreground service.