# when screen off timer and animation stopped

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I have a timer and animation in my flutter project but when ı screen of my phone timer and animation stoped.
I want both of them to continue with the phone off.
How can ı do that?

Comment: see this link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924890/how-do-i-run-code-in-the-background-even-with-the-screen-off