# Detect window closing action flutter desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, flutter-desktop

I am working on flutter desktop application and want to show alert dialog before closing window. Could not get any information about detecting window closing action.

Can anyone tell me how to do this. Thankx.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115627/flutter-desktop-how-to-catch-closure-button/63128108#63128108

Comment: Could you please help me out for code. I don't know exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the existing [flutter_window_close](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close) package. Check out the example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close/example).

This plugin lets your Flutter app a chance to confirm if the user wants to close your app. It works on desktop platforms including ***Windows***, ***macOS*** and ***Linux***.

Try to explore as well [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window).