# How to run function when the app shut down?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send data to my database with a function and I need to do it when the application shut down (not when it's on background). Is there a clean way to do this?

EDIT : I'm looking for a solution that work on both IOS and Android

Comment: Do you mean just right before it is shut down?

Comment: @David, yes exactly. When the application catch that it will shut down, I need to send my data right before the shut down.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184497/how-to-execute-code-before-app-exit-flutter
?

Comment: Yes, but the AppLifecycleState.detached isn't really what I'm lookiong for. This state is trigger when the application is still running in background. I really need to catch the moment when the user (or the app itself) shutdown the application.

Comment: I think, you could do that with "isolates".

Comment: I tried, but doesn't work on IOS.

Comment: Im facing the same problem did you solve?