# How to play and stop audio at specific time?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

I have an audio player app using just_audio plugin. How to play and stop audio at a specific time?

For example, I have an audio file that is 20 minutes long. I want when I press play button, the audio will run at the 5th minute and stop at the 8th minute.

Here is my code:

```
void _setInitialPlaylist() async {
    final myAudio1 = Uri.parse("asset:///audio/myAudio.mp3"); // I want this audio play at 00.05.00, stop at 00.08.00
    final myAudio2 = Uri.parse("asset:///audio/myAudio.mp3"); // I want this audio play at 00.09.00, stop at 00.12.00
    final myAudio3 = Uri.parse("asset:///audio/myAudio.mp3"); // I want this audio play at 00.15.00, stop at 00.19.00
    _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
      AudioSource.uri(myAudio1, tag: 'myAudio1'),
      AudioSource.uri(myAudio2, tag: 'myAudio2'),
      AudioSource.uri(myAudio3, tag: 'myAudio3'),
    ]);
    await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(_playlist);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
await player.setClip(start: Duration(seconds: 10), end: Duration(seconds: 20));
await player.play(); // Waits until the clip has finished playing
```

In your case it becomes:

```
await player.setClip(start: Duration(minutes: 5), end: Duration(minutes: 8));
await player.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the seek method to seek the desired time and then start a timer and pause when the timer ends.

```dart
int result = await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(minutes: 5));
Timer(Duration(minutes: 3), () {
    int result = await audioPlayer.pause();
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work if the application terminated. the audio doesn't stop, can u help?

Comment: @Thaiveng You can pause or stop on the player in the termination commands mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184497/how-to-execute-code-before-app-exit-flutter

Answer (score 0):

For pausing,
`_audioPlayer.pause()`

For starting audio at a specific time,
`_audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds:timeInMilliseconds));`
`_audioPlayer.play();`

One more thing i want to add _audioPlayer.resume is not working in newer versions so below code can be used for resuming,
`_audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds:player.position.inMilliseconds));`
`_audioPlayer.play();`

I was facing the 'resuming' problem, may be this could help someone in future.