How to Notify Server When User Kills an App in Flutter?
I'm developing a Flutter application where I need to notify the server whenever a user explicitly kills the app (e.g., swiping the app from the recent apps list or force stopping the app). I want to perform certain actions on the server-side, such as updating the user's status or performing cleanup tasks, when the app is terminated by the user.
I've explored various approaches, including using app lifecycle events and Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), but I'm unsure about the best practice to achieve this functionality.
Can anyone provide guidance or suggest an effective method to detect when a user kills the app and notify the server accordingly in a Flutter application?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    switch (taskName) {
      case 'updateStatusTask':
        await updateStatusOnServer();
        break;
      default:
        print('Unknown task: $taskName');
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

class AppLifecycleObserver extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      await updateStatusOnServer();
    }
  }

  void _makeAPICall() async {
    // Implement your API call logic here
    // You can use the http package or any other networking library
    // to make the API request
    // Example:
    // final response = await http.get('https://api.example.com/endpoint');
    // Handle the API response as needed
    print("app killed");
  }
}

Future<void> updateStatusOnServer() async {
  // Api calling
}


This is not possible, an app when killed by the user or OS does not get notified, the process is simply stopped

What do you intend to do for other scenarios, such as when the user turns on airplane mode or otherwise loses its ability to talk to your server? If the answer is "the behavior should be the same", then your framing of the problem is wrong. It is not "was the app killed" but "is the server receiving information from the app". You would need to set up some sort of timeout on the server, where if the app has not communicated in X amount of time, the server assumes that the app is no longer reachable and takes whatever steps it is that you are intending.

@tyczj, when I was in R&D to achieve this feature, there were solutions like using workmanager package / sending notifications and also some solutions available on StackOverflow.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540409/is-there-a-way-to-call-specific-code-right-before-the-app-is-killed-or-moves-to


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184497/how-to-execute-code-before-app-exit-flutter


But I am not sure how to achieve it.

@CommonsWare, thanks for suggesting other scenarios. But, yes the behavior should be the same when the app is also in airplane mode. You're saying that I have to deal with this problem being resolved on the server side?

@Mahipalsinh if you app is killed workmanager may or may not run, it is device dependent so it should not be considered reliable. The simple answer is you cannot do what you are trying to do and probably need to rethink what you are doing in the app

Cloud function with a deadman timer is probably the only solution.  You can't count on any action from a killed app. especially over a network.

"You're saying that I have to deal with this problem being resolved on the server side?" -- yes. If the app cannot connect to the server, the app cannot tell the server "I am not able to connect to the server". Rather, the server needs to determine on its own that the app is not able to connect to the server, by not seeing recent activity from the app.

@RandalSchwartz Would you kindly provide further information or any examples?

You can achieve it in some way by AppLifecycleListener by use of didRequestAppExit (overriding it then call your code that notify API) .

Could you maybe use a Web Socket that opens on app launch, and then when the socket is dropped by the client (by airplane mode, exiting app, drop in internet, etc.) the server does its cleanup? And then on the client side, if you ever drop the socket you could inform the user somehow/adjust the app's state and/or attempt to reconnect with a new session?

@G3nt_M3caj, i tried with AppLifecycleListener but API call did not work.
